# Mac OS X: trying to link (ld) against a framework

Tags: macos, frameworks, linker

I am reading "Advanced Mac OS X Programming" by Mark and Aaron. I can't get one terminal statement to work correctly :

> cc -g -o useadd -F./Adder/build -framework Adder useadd.m

It's on page 45 - Chapter 3 (Libraries). As you can see, I am trying to link useadd.m against a framework created using Xcode. When I run this command, I get this error :

> ld: framework not found Adder
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I made sure that the folder /Adder/build exists under the current directory. Inside that folder, there is another one : Adder.build that contains the framework. I have been trying every possible combination, but the linker just can't find my framework.

I am using Mac OS X Leopard, and I think the book was published before Leopard, when Tiger was still the most recent Mac OS.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path specified with the -F option has to point to a directory which contains the framework (not in a subdirectory). So try -F./Adder/build/Adder.build, if it's really in there. But usually Xcode puts build products in a directory name Debug or Release in the build dir. The Adder.build is only for intermediate build results.

Comment: Hi, thanks, in general, it's important to make sure that the folder you specify through -F contains the framework (look for the .framework "extension")