# pip install PySide fails QtCore Framework check (OS X)

Tags: qt, python-2.7, python-3.x, osx-mountain-lion, pyside

### The error

When I run `pip install PySide` – whether in a virtual environment or not – build fails with the following error:

```
... [lots of build info, including a few warnings but no errors, for shiboken]

Linking CXX executable shiboken

ld: framework not found QtCore

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Seeing as I have QtCore installed and the framework present (see below), I'm not sure why that should be.

### Setup info

#### Software versions

- OS X 10.8.2
- Qt 4.8.4 from the developer distributed [binaries](http://qt-project.org/downloads)
- Python 3.3 installed and working normally
- XCode 4.6
- Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.24) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
  Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
- Virtual environment generating using `pyvenv` (with and without `--no-site-packages`)

#### Other configurations attempted

- Python 2.7 installed and working normally
- Virtual environment generated using `mkvirtualenv` (with and without `--no-site-packages`)

  - **virtualenv** 1.8.4
  - **mkvirtualenv** 3.6

#### System configuration

I've confirmed that QtCore is in fact installed correctly: `ls /Library/Frameworks` shows a number of Frameworks, including `QtCore.Framework`.

My path currently includes both `/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework` and `/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.Framework/Versions/4` – the former of which has a symbolic link to the component in the latter location. I've even tried it with `/Library/Frameworks`, though for obvious reasons I didn't expect that to help and it did not.

### Other notes

I've tried the same thing with `easy_install` and by doing a pull from the Git repository and building manually using `setup.py`. As one would expect, they all return the same results.

#### Things I've already read

- [PyPi Installation walkthrough](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide#installing-pyside-from-source-on-a-unix-system-ubuntu-12-04-lts)
- [Link error: QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore for architecture x86_64 (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065085/link-error-qtcore-framework-versions-4-qtcore-for-architecture-x86-64) – but it seems the linker is already asking for the framework, based on the error message I'm receiving.
- [Mac OS X: trying to link (ld) against a framework (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024704/mac-os-x-trying-to-link-ld-against-a-framework) – general info on linking against Frameworks; again, I seem to have this covered.
- [OSX deployment target confusion for 2.8.10 (CMake Mailing list)](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2012-November/052688.html) – looks like a very similar error, but I don't have direct control of the `-isysroot` flag using `pip` (or `easy_install` or even `python setup.py`) for one and for another, installation structure seems to have changed substantially between OS X 10.6 and 10.8. For example, `/Developer` no longer has the `SDKs` directory in it at all.
- [CMake bug report 0013765](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/bug_revision_view_page.php?rev_id=958) – this one looks *exactly* the same, but appears to have been patched, so I'm not sure why it would still be causing me a problem.

#### Preferences

I'm not using a package manager like Homebrew or MacPorts at this time, and I'd prefer not to, either, as I need to get as close as possible to a platform-agnostic installation procedure for this (we're looking at doing cross-platform development; I'll ultimately be targeting Windows applications primarily, but need to see if it's workable on my Mac development machine outside a VM).

It needs to be able to work with a Python 3-style virtual environment (`pyvenv`) setup, as that's our preferred means of isolating our particular requirements.